# How to propagate security Principal from WebSphere to JBoss?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, ejb-3.0, java-ee-6, jaas

I am building an application that needs to call a remote EJB 3.0 which is hosted on JBoss 4 and I need to propagate the Principal from WebSphere to JBoss. I have written a custom login module and a custom Principal and registered them in WebSphere.

From any layer in WAS environment(web or EJB layer) I can recover the principal that I have authenticated using the LoginModule, so from WebSphere I can do:

```
Principal principal = context.getCallerPrincipal();
String name = principal.getName(); ....
```

and this will properly return the authenticated principal and its properties.

I can also access a remote EJB hosted in JBoss successfully from WebSphere but the problem in this case is that whenever I try to recover the Principal from JBoss calling getCallerPrincipal() JBoss container throws an Exception:

```
[10/2/12 12:56:37:594 BRT] 0000007f BusinessExcep E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "remoteJBossEJBCall" on bean "BeanId(JBossRemoteEJBCall#ejbModule.jar#WAS_EJB, null)". Exception data: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No valid security context for the caller identity; nested exception is: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No valid security context for the caller identity
```

....

I have already set the WebSphere Global Security to propagate security attributes but this also didn't fix the issue:

[image: WebSphere outbound security propagation]

I have done all steps documented at:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tsec_enablesecattprop.html

but still doesn't work.